C# - MS Test - inexistent Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading 17.1.0.0
I try adding Threading functionalities in my test classes.
Issue:
While the only version I can install is 17.8, as I run the test, I keep getting this error
Test method *******TestMethod_ReturnsTrue threw exception: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=17.1.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.

Context:
Since the test are UI related, I need to wait for UI thread or call a dispatcher
public void *******TestMethod_ReturnsTrue()
{
    dispatcher.Invoke(async () => 
    {
        await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();
        .... 
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    });
}

So far, I cannot use any threading related functions
I tried:

I checked all project files, there is no 17.1.0.0 references anywhere
I tried syncing the package versions between my solution and the test unit solution (*)
I tried updating all packages but then the manifest does not load anymore, so I cannot build the solution anymore (**)
I also tried [UITestMethod] but no matter what this does not get recognized

Is there a way to fix this ?
Thanks for your help, let me know if you need more infos

(*)
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK" Version="17.1.32210.191" ExcludeAssets="runtime">
      <IncludeAssets>compile; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools" Version="17.1.4057">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>

(**)
Error trying to read the VSIX manifest file "Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskParameter+TaskParameterTaskItem". Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 


